# Prevent automatic selection on textbox focus

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, textbox, controls

When you use a tab key to select a textbox, all text in it is automatically selected. What's the easiest way to prevent this from happening? (Setting the selection to none in Enter or GotFocus events doesn't work)

Thanks (-:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<sub>(I'm assuming that you are using WinForms)</sub>

What you have said you have already tried does work.

If you handle the [Enter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter.aspx) event on the text box, you can set the selection to nothing:

```
Private Sub textBox_Enter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim position As Integer = textBox.Text.Length
    textBox.Select(position, position)
End Sub
```

This sets the selection to be a zero-length string starting at the end of the text currently in the text box. This is to position the caret at the end of the current text.

Comment: Oh, that works, thanks! I guess there is a difference when just setting the selection start and selection length, and using .Select. Also, textbox.Select(textbox.selectionstart, textbox.selectionstart) works better for my needs.

Comment: don't forget `textBox.ScrollToCaret()`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `textBox.DeSelectAll()`.

Comment: For those interested, this appears to put the caret at the beginning of the text box. The other answer puts the caret at the end of the text box.